# Facebook Scrumptious sample app won't build

Tags: facebook, xcode4

I did exactly what they do in the video. However, when I get to the scrumptious app and try to build/run it, mine fails. It says: "Parse Issue. Expected a type."

Here are the three lines that it thinks are broken (located in the ACAccountStore.h):

```
    // Returns the account type object matching the account type identifier. See
    // ACAccountType.h for well known account type identifiers
    - (ACAccountType *)accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:(NSString
    *)typeIdentifier;

    // Returns the accounts matching a given account type.
    - (NSArray *)accountsWithAccountType:(ACAccountType *)accountType;

// this method is called on an arbitrary queue.
- (void)requestAccessToAccountsWithType:(ACAccountType *)accountType 
                  withCompletionHandler:(ACAccountStoreRequestAccessCompletionHandler)handler;
```

Here is a link to the tutorial. I only didn't even make it two min in before I hit this wall.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/

I am running Xcode v4.4.1.

Answer (score 1):

From Step 1 of that tutorial:

*Install the Prerequisites*

You need **Xcode 4.5**, and optionally, Git

Try upgrading XCode and see if it builds with the recommended version.

Comment: Well that might not be the issue, but it's the first thing i noticed